# PHP JSON Search with key name

Tags: php, json

I have following JSON Data

```
"12-305":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SALADS","ord":"0","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"6","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"All Salads","id":"305","icon":"","price":"0"}]
"12-270":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SALADS","ord":"1","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"6","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"No Salad","id":"270","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12-273":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"No Sauce","id":"273","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"15-19":[{"catid":"15","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"2","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"BBQ Sauce","id":"19","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12-19":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"BBQ Sauce","id":"19","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"15-20":[{"catid":"15","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"3","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"2","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"Garlic Sauce","id":"20","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12-20":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"3","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"Garlic Sauce","id":"20","icon":"","price":"0"}]`
```

I want to only grab rows that contains "catid":"12" or key is like "12-" is this posible with using php json?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  See [ask] and [mcve].  Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_decode('...your json string...');
$rows_that_contains_catid_12 = array();
$allowed_catid_values = array("12","12-");
foreach($json as &$v) {
    foreach($v as &$rv){
        if(in_array($rv['catid'],$allowed_catid_values))
            $rows_that_contains_catid_12[] = $rv;
    }
}
```

$rows_that_contains_catid_12 holds your result...
Regards

Comment: Thank you. I have manage to find a solution myself. your method works too with few tweeks. This method pulls all json data and loops through. The performance with a lardge json data file would be a problem. I played with the json data and removed part of keyname after "-" and pulled only json rows with keyname "12". this way I didnt need to loop all the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by tweaking the Json key. Removed characters after "-" which left following Json File

```
"12":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SALADS","ord":"0","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"6","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"All Salads","id":"305","icon":"","price":"0"}]
"12":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SALADS","ord":"1","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"6","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"No Salad","id":"270","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"No Sauce","id":"273","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"15":[{"catid":"15","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"2","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"BBQ Sauce","id":"19","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"2","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"BBQ Sauce","id":"19","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"15":[{"catid":"15","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"3","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"2","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"Garlic Sauce","id":"20","icon":"","price":"0"}],
"12":[{"catid":"12","fname":"SAUCE","ord":"3","show":"1","free":"0","extra":"0","hasextra":"1","filterorder":"1","maxS":"3","Valid":"0","Phone":"1","Web":"1","ovalue":"Garlic Sauce","id":"20","icon":"","price":"0"}]`
```

And pulled only key names 12 with this code

```
 //my Json data is stored in a txt file
    $catid= 12;
    $data= fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."URL TO DATA",'r'); 
    $json = fgets($data); 
    $subitems =json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $subitems =$subitems[$catid];
```